# While connecting devices to Azure cloud , which is advisable to use - Azure IoT Hub or Azure IoT Central?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, arduino-esp8266, azure-iot-central

So basically i'm working on a project which involves getting data using a sensor (say analyzing temperature/vibration etc.) and then transfer the data to cloud (Azure) which in turn can be used to show users the data - in an app/website. Do i use Azure IoT Hub or Azure IoT Central to store , stream and make use of data so that i can display the respective data of each user when they logon to the website?

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT Central is a set of pre-built IoT applications while IoT Hub is a service.  You either use or build your own solution.